# Scala Tour Implicit Conversion Example

Tags: scala

I am having a hard time understanding what this piece of code does exactly:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def list2ordered[A](x: List[A])
    (implicit elem2ordered: A => Ordered[A]): Ordered[List[A]] =
  new Ordered[List[A]] { 
    //replace with a more useful implementation
    def compare(that: List[A]): Int = 1
  }
```

It comes from the Scala Tour and it is in the section "Implicit Conversions". I understand that `list2ordered` takes a `List[A]` that comes from the left hand side of `List(1, 2, 3) <= List(4, 5)` and `that` in `compare` function is the right hand side.

However, why is `A => Ordered[A]` that and not `List[A] => Ordered[List[A]]` ? I am a bit confused as to what this piece of code actually does.

Comment: The end result of the implicit conversion is a `Ordered[List[A]]`. However, in order to order to compare two lists, you first need that their elements can also be compared. So this implicit conversion demands an implicit evidence of a transformation from `A` to an `Order[A]` - Anyways, implicit conversions are discouraged and this specific use case is better modeled by a typeclass instead, look for `Ordering`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable. The example code isn't terribly illuminating largely because the code, as presented, doesn't need the `A`-to-`Ordered[A]` conversion. We can comment it out and everything still "works" (such as it is).

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def list2ordered[A](xs: List[A]
                          //)(implicit elem2ordered: A => Ordered[A]
                             ): Ordered[List[A]] =
  new Ordered[List[A]] {
    def compare(ys: List[A]): Int = 
      1 //this is always greater than that
  }
```

We can even implement a meaningful (if rather simple minded) `List` ordering and still not need the `A`-to-`Ordered[A]` conversion.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def list2ordered[A](xs: List[A]
                          //)(implicit elem2ordered: A => Ordered[A]
                             ): Ordered[List[A]] =
  new Ordered[List[A]] {
    def compare(ys: List[A]): Int =
      xs.length - ys.length //shorter List before longer List
  }
```

But if `List` order depends on element order, then we need that conversion.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def list2ordered[A](xs: List[A]
                            )(implicit elem2ordered: A => Ordered[A]
                             ): Ordered[List[A]] =
  new Ordered[List[A]] {
    //3rd element determines order
    def compare(ys: List[A]): Int = (xs.lift(2),ys.lift(2)) match {
      case (None,None) => 0
      case (None, _)   => -1
      case (_, None)   => 1
      case (Some(x), Some(y)) => 
        x compare y //implicit conversion needed
    }
  }
```

Just to drive home the point, let's simplify this order-by-3rd-element arrangement by modifying the required conversion.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def list2ordered[A](xs: List[A]
                            )(implicit elem2ordered: Option[A] => Ordered[Option[A]]
                             ): Ordered[List[A]] =
  new Ordered[List[A]] {
    def compare(ys: List[A]): Int =
      xs.lift(2) compare ys.lift(2)  //3rd element determines order
  }
```